# How to modify an array so that i want to get an array with an incremented value of some array values

Tags: php, loops, codeigniter, for-loop

I come across a scenario where i have an array like this

```
 Array
    (
        [24] => 24
        [25] => 25
        [26] => 26
        [27] => 27
        [28] => 28
        [29] => 29
    )
```

But i want a resultant array by including the incremented value of last and decremented value of first like this

```
Array
(
    [24] => 24
    [25] => 25
    [26] => 26
    [27] => 27
    [28] => 28
    [29] => 29
    [23] => 23
    [30] => 30
)
```

I know this is a little bit strange. But can anyone help me to find the result.

I found out the values

```
$f=reset($res);
$f=$f-1;

$l=end($res);
$l=$l+1;
```

but no idea on how to push into array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably safer to use `min` and `max` to find the lowest and highest values, otherwise your code wouldn't work on your result array (`reset($array)` on the output still returns `24`, not `23`):

```
$min = min($array) - 1;
$max = max($array) + 1;
$array[$min] = $min;
$array[$max] = $max;
print_r($array);
```

Output:

Array

```
(
    [24] => 24
    [25] => 25
    [26] => 26
    [27] => 27
    [28] => 28
    [29] => 29
    [23] => 23
    [30] => 30
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/789KS)

Answer (score 0):

Under the condition that the key is always equal to the value you can try that:

```
$data = [
  24 => 24,25 => 25,26 => 26,27 => 27,28 => 28,29 => 29,
];

$first = reset($data)-1;
$end = end($data)+1;
$data[$first] = $first;
$data[$end] = $end;
```

But I think you do not want the first and last, but min and max.